# MIP programming for fairness

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory, mixed-integer-programming, fair-division

I have a MIP model that allocates 24 rides between 6 drivers (with many constraints irrelevant here), and an important part of my objective is splitting the rides fairly.

The easiest implementation I could think of is to punish for any driver that gets less (or more?) than the average 24/6=4 rides.

However, I saw that in many works and publications the concept of leximin fairness is used and considered intuitive and justified. Given an allocation `y`, we sort it and then compare it to other allocations lexicographically, and if it's larger it's considered fairer.

Question: why doesn't this criteria always agree with my easy implementation? e.g.

$y^1$=`<2,3,3,3,3,10>` is considered leximin fairer than $y^2$=`<2,2,5,5,5,5>`. However:

1. If the punishment would be $\sum_i abs(avg-y_i)$, than $y^1$ would be punished by 12 while $y^2$ which would be punished only by 8
2. If the punishment would be $\sum_i max(0, avg-y_i)$, than $y^1$ would be punished by 6 while $y^2$ which would be punished only by 4

is this just a matter of subjective preferences in the definition of fairness? or is there a bug in my implementation? Is there a known way of incorporating leximin fairness in a MIP model?